# Command line: general command for file rename

Tags: command-line, batch

I'm facing a problem. How do I replace that code:

```
if exist path\file1.temp rename path\*.zds *.file1
if exist path\file2.temp rename path\*.zds *.file2
```

with something general, so it picks `<filename>.temp` and rename `*.zds` to `*.<filename>`

Thanks

Comment: Simply create a batch file with each of the name parts as a positional parameter: see [here](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax.html).

Comment: So there is only **ONE** file with extension `.temp` present in `path`? Otherwise after the first rename no files with the extension `.zds` would be left?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With this initial tree :

```
> tree a:\ /f
A:\
└───test
        bar.zds
        baz.zds
        filex.temp
        foo.zds
```

This cmd line:

```
for %A in (A:\test\*.temp) do @Ren "A:\Test\*.zds" "*.%~nA"
```

Will yield this result:

```
> tree a:\ /f
A:\
└───test
        bar.filex
        baz.filex
        filex.temp
        foo.filex
```

In a batch file double the percent signs:

```
@Echo off
Set "Folder=A:\Test"
for %%A in (%Folder%\*.temp) do Ren "%Folder%\*.zds" "*.%%~nA"
```